# I wonder if my PhD from Turkey is recognized in Germany or not?

Tags: phd

I have got my PhD on Production management and marketing from Marmara University in Istanbul. How can I check if my PhD is recognized in Germany? Please help me by introducing an organization in Berlin that I can go and ask directly.

Comment: What do you mean "recognized"?  What do you want to do?  Apply for a job?  Use the title "Dr"?  Something else?

Answer (score 10):

According to the [anabin database](http://anabin.kmk.org/no_cache/filter/institutionen.html) ("The database provides information for evaluating foreign education certificates and supporting authorities, employers and individuals to classify a foreign qualification in the German education system."), Marmara University is recognized in the H+ category, meaning that:

> Die Institutionen dieses Typs sind im jeweiligen Herkunftsland in maßgeblicher Weise als Hochschulen anerkannt (akkreditiert, attestiert ua) und ausgehend davon in Deutschland als Hochschulen anzusehen. Besonders für Länder der ehemaligen sozialistischen Welt sind auch Forschungsinstitute erfasst, da an ihnen Promotionen und Habilitationen möglich sind.

or from Google Translate:

> The institutions of this type are recognized in their country of origin in significant ways as universities (accredited, certified, etc.) and starting it regarded in Germany as universities. Especially for countries of the former socialist world and research institutes are recognized as promotions and Habilitation are available to them. Since these qualifications are equivalent to universities, research institutions are also assigned to this category. Attention! The classification as H + simply means that accounts which have been achieved in this device can be subjected to equivalence study in higher education. A preliminary decision as to whether the financial statements of these means can be assimilated German university degrees, thus is not connected.

[image: Screenshot]

So, it would seem that your qualification is recognised in this sense, but if you are thinking of applying e.g. for a postdoc, you should write to your prospective employer(s) detailing your situation and what this equivalency relates to in terms of your job search.